# Difference between function components and component classes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is following a tutorial in React JS.

```
  class Square extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
        >
            {this.props.value}
        </button>
        );
    }
  }

   function Square(props) {
        return (
            <button className="square" onClick={props.onClick}>
            {props.value}
            </button>
        );
    }
```

above components do the same thing.there's a statement in the tutorial as follows

"When we modified the Square to be a function component, we also changed onClick={() => this.props.onClick()} to a shorter onClick={props.onClick} (note the lack of parentheses on both sides)."

I don't understand why there aren't parentheses on the right side in the function component? is it not a function call?

Answer (score 1):

> is it not a function call?

No, it isn't. It is a function. You are passing it to be the value of the `onClick` property.

This is a function that does nothing except call `foo` and return its value.

```
() => foo()
```

This is the function foo:

```
foo
```

The net result is more-or-less the same unless `foo` cares about the value of `this` or the arguments it gets.

---

If you added `()` to the short version, you would call the function immediately and pass the return value to `onClick`. Since that return value (probably) isn't a function, and you don't want the function to run until the click happens, that wouldn't be helpful.

---

```js
function run_me(a_function) {
    a_function();
}

function foo() {
    console.log("foo has run");
}

run_me(foo);
run_me(() => foo());
run_me(foo());
```

Comment: That's right about callback concept in js, ok, but lets me return to react and ask again: why in case of the component class we had to assign _returned value_ of onClick function, but in case of function component, we had to the _reference_ of onClick function?

Comment: "why in case of the component class we assigned returned value of onClick function" — You have two examples on `onClick={someValue}` in your code. In the first case, the value is a new arrow function which calls one function (`() => this.props.onClick()`). In the second case you have an existing function (`props.onClick`). You are **not** *calling* a function and passing its return value to `onClick={here}`.

Answer (score 0):

When passing a handler we actually need to pass a reference to a function.

> I don't understand why there aren't parentheses on the right side in
>   the function component? is it not a function call?

When you put *parentheses* you are invoking the function.
So when doing this:

```
onClick={props.onClick()}
```

We are passing the returned value of that function instead of a reference to it.

Comment: While true, that ignores the `() =>` in the example with the parentheses at the end so doesn't really describe the situation here.

Comment: hmm, are you talking about the `class` example? isn't that falls under _passing a function reference_, or because it's anonymous you think that's different?

Comment: My point is that `onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}` and `onClick={props.onClick}` **both** pass a function to `onClick`., and neither invoke it immediately.

Comment: Indeed, that is my point as well. AFAIK, the OP asks why we are not doing `onClick={props.onClick()}` so this is what i was trying to explain. i guess i wasn't communicating clearly with my answer

Comment: Ahhhh. I see now.